# Shadowsocks: Doesn't communication with just one server look suspicious to the GFW?

Tags: vpn, detection, censorship, socks5

From what I understand, [Shadowsocks](https://shadowsocks.org/en/index.html) masks SOCKS5 traffic as HTTPS traffic, so that the [GFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) cannot detect it by packet inspection. Shadowsocks can be installed on my own server, naturally. For usage, I would establish a connection with a Shadowsocks client and point my browser's SOCKS5 configuration to a certain port on localhost. Now, all my traffic when browsing the web is exchanged between my PC and my server, via my ISP. And here I don't understand:

*Doesn't it look suspicious to the GFW if an individual's daily Internet traffic is happening between his PC and just one server? Wouldn't it be trivial for the GFW to eliminate Shadowsocks connections by blocking IPs?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible? Sure! Will it be done? I doubt.

Unless your traffic is on the top chart, you are a small fish. And they don't have resources or people or willingness to pursue every single private VPN service out there, because there are more interesting things to pursue.

IPv6 addresses are plentiful and cheap this days. If you are concerned about being blocked, rent a VPS or two, with IPv6 addressing, and have `shadowsocks` listen on every address. Change to a random address at random intervals and you can conceal your VPN a little more.

Comment: Well, in the end (end of last year), I realized that Internet in public places such as cafes is generally slow as molasses. Asking the waiter to restart the router sometimes makes things quicker, but eventually the slowdown will occur again. So throttling seems to be a real thing. For fast unrestricted Internet access I was using my phone with a China Mobile Hong Kong SIM. Mobile communication is routed out of country without filtering.